# Pinch zoom inside listbox not working in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, pinchzoom

I have a Listbox that displays image and need to have pinch zoom for the image. I use ScrollViewer to achieve pinch zoom.

So my Listbox data template looks this.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Transparent"
        BorderThickness="1"
        Background="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}"
        Margin="0">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Background="Transparent"
          Holding="Grid_Holding"
          Margin="8">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource RedBrush}"
                BorderThickness="1"
                CornerRadius="20"
                Width="150"
                Height="170"
                Grid.Column="0">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                          ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="True"
                          ZoomMode="Enabled"
                          MinZoomFactor="0.8"
                          MaxZoomFactor="20">
                <Image Stretch="Uniform"
                       Width="150"
                       Height="170">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding MainImage}"
                                     DecodePixelWidth="400"/>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="15 0 0 0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                       Style="{StaticResource SavedImageHeadingTextBlockStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

The problem is that when I use the same code outside the ListBox Pinch zoom works great. But inside ListBox the Pinchzoom doesn't work.

Any help will be apprieciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you probably shouldn't be trying to do this anyway. If you get it to work, you're going to end up with a pretty frustrating UI where your ListView may not scroll depending on whether or not the internal ScrollViewer is under the finger (and swallowing touch).

What may or may not work in your scenario is to rather use a FlipView (instead of ListView). A FlipView handles a ScrollViewer in the ItemTemplate pretty well, and you'll end up with a better experience for the user.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can understand what u say. but my requirement is to have zoom in list box items. Since it is home page I cant have flipview there.